# I need to check the occurrence of a particular symbol at the beginning of my String

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to check the occurrence of a particular symbol say `#$` at the beginning of my String.

Simply, I need to get the

`boolean symbolExist true` for all the following cases,

- `#$MyString`
- `#$<Space>myString`
- `#$<Space><Space>myString`
- `#$<Space><space>my#$String`
- `#$My#$String`
- etc. (never mind what ever coming after the 2 characters)

`boolean symbolExist false` for

- `MyString#$`
- `My#$string`
- etc .

Comment: Not that the word *occurrence* has double C, a double R, and an E not an A. This is the second most frequently misspelled word in the English language, following only *separate*, which is first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `startsWith` method of `String` class:

```
String s = "#$test";
System.out.println(s.startsWith("#$"));
```

the output is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In String Class we have one called boolean startsWith(String prefix) using this method you can solve your problem.

```
String content = "#$MyString";

if(content.startsWith("#$")) //This will return true if String starts with "#$"
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
boolean symbolExists ;
String myString;
if(myString.startsWith("#$"))
    symbolExists = true;
else
    symbolExists = false;
```